# Variable space to replace \qquad

Tags: spacing

I am trying to create my own macro and cannot find a way to do the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\newcommand{\conv}[2]{\indent#1\qquad\tabto#2\\}
\begin{document}
\conv{$c$}{The velocity of light in vacuum, set to $c=1$.}
\conv{$G$}{The universal gravitational constant, set to $G=1$.}
\conv{$\mu$}{Greek indices are used for four-vectors, $\mu=\, t\,,r\,,\theta\,,\phi\,.$}
\conv{$i$}{Latin indices are used for spatial vectors, $i=\,r\,,\theta\,,\phi\,$ or $i=x\,,y\,,z\,.$}
\conv{$\textbf{x}$}{Bold vectors are spatial vectors.}
\end{document}
```

The results give almost what I want only the \qquad makes the second argument at a fixed distance of the first, I would like all the second arguments to start at the same distance of the margin. I know it is similar to the \nomenclature package but for unknown reasons the package doesn't work on my file...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your problem seems to be simpler to solve with use of  `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide `\tabto` with a length argument specifying the tabbed location, for example (here) 0.8in.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\conv}[2]{\indent#1\qquad\tabto{.8in}#2\\}
\begin{document}
\conv{$c$}{The velocity of light in vacuum, set to $c=1$.}
\conv{$G$}{The universal gravitational constant, set to $G=1$.}
\conv{$\mu$}{Greek indices are used for four-vectors, $\mu=\, t\,,r\,,\theta\,,\phi\,.$}
\conv{$i$}{Latin indices are used for spatial vectors, $i=\,r\,,\theta\,,\phi\,$ or $i=x\,,y\,,z\,.$}
\conv{$\textbf{x}$}{Bold vectors are spatial vectors.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Had not thought of this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in comment, it is simpler to write your list of variable as table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$} l}
    c   & The velocity of light in vacuum, set to $c=1$.        \\
    G   & The universal gravitational constant, set to $G=1$.   \\
    \mu & Greek indices are used for four-vectors, $\mu=\, t\,,r\,,\theta\,,\phi\,.$    \\
    i   & Latin indices are used for spatial vectors, $i=\,r\,,\theta\,,\phi\,$ or $i=x\,,y\,,z\,.$    \\
    \mathbf{x}  & Bold vectors are spatial vectors.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works better this way! thank you!